# Remove composer from PHP project?

Tags: composer-php

Is there a way to build project, created with composer, remove all «trash» files and save all dependencies?
Or i can use it as is - upload all directories to server and that's all?

Comment: Could you please shed more light on this, what do you mean by *<<trash>>* file? What kind of server are you deploying to: Shared Hosting or VPS?

Comment: For example i got repository from github and i need to use only one library, but it depends on other 5 libraries. Composer creates his own autoloader and other «half empty» subfolders from other projects.
I wanna delete composer, and replace folders without changing any namespaces.

To be clear, i want to `replace App/sub/sub/someLibrary/sub` to `App/someLibrary/....`

P.S. I'm using dedicated server with all possible access .